# How to retrieve relaystate value sent by IDP in POST request body

Tags: java, spring-boot, saml-2.0, spring-saml, spring-security-saml2

I'm trying to configure authentication (SSO- SP initiated) with OKTA as IDP where my spring boot application will be working as a Service Provider through SAML. I am trying to retrieve relaystate parameter sent by IDP in http post request body. I am retrieving saml response using @authenticationPrincipal but I am not able to find any sample code or documentation to get relayState. Can someone help me with this? Sample code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `SP-initiated` flow, it's Service provider (SP) that pass the relay params and want to receive the same after the authentication from the IdP.
If you've the `Authentication` object you can easily get the relay state as mentioned below:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();        
SAMLCredentials credentials = (SAMLCredentials) authentication.getCredentials();
String relayState = credentials.getRelayState();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried using this but getting the exception: java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLCredential (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLCredential is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Comment: Which version of springboot, spring security and spring-security-saml2 are you using?